# Flask App failing on heroku, but working with foreman

Tags: python, heroku, flask, foreman

I'm trying to deploy a fairly basic app with Heroku, and I've been successful before, but for some reason I'm getting an import error when I try now. Foreman start works with no issues, but when I try to start the application up, something seems to happen that breaks imports. This is the log message I get:

```
heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `python manage.py runserver -p 40309`
app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
app[web.1]:   File "manage.py", line 6, in <module>
app[web.1]: ImportError: No module named SpoolEngine
app[web.1]:     from SpoolEngine import app
heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=tranquil-taiga-1563.herokuapp.com fwd="66.31.20.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=tranquil-taiga-1563.herokuapp.com fwd="66.31.20.171" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
```

This is my Procfile:

```
web: python manage.py runserver -p $PORT
```

and this is the `manage.py` file I'm using to start everything up:

```
import os, sys
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))

from flask.ext.script import Manager, Server
from SpoolEngine import app

manager = Manager(app)

manager.add_command("runserver", Server(
    use_debugger=True,
    use_reloader=True,
    host='0.0.0.0')
)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    manager.run()
```

I'm sorry if this is something silly that I've done, but I'm pretty new to this realm and would really appreciate some pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guessing here: your code shows

```
sys.path.append(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..')))
```

So locally you have some packages installed in manage.py's parent directory, but that's not the case in Heroku.

Just to debug, I would also add

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

to the very top of manage.py, and compare outputs. You can look for your modules in the output of the local run, and then `heroku run bash` and look at what's in the directories printed by the remote run.

Comment: btw -- you do know to be careful (read: avoid) with the debugger when deploying to Heroku, yes? Just sayin' :)

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. This was totally it! Also yes, I know, this is just for a demo.

Answer (score -1):

I would bet it's because you're trying to run the built-in Flask development server instead of letting Heroku run it in their normal framework (which is gunicorn, I believe). You can't run both.

Try reading through these instructions again:

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python

and try getting rid of the manage.py script - I don't think you need it.

Comment: Heroku doesn't have a "normal framework" that example you linked just shows them using gunicorn (which has to be specified in the Procfile). There's no gunicorn involved here, but thanks for the answer.