# Heroku app works in Foreman, but behaves incorrectly when deployed

Tags: python, debugging, heroku, flask

I have a Flask app deployed on Heroku that works perfectly well locally in Foreman, but is bugged when deployed.

The app attempts to build a stock chart using symbols provided in the GET method. I have an IOError exception set in case a given stock symbol does not exist. Normally, any invalid stock symbols will be ignored, and any valid stock symbols will have their charts rendered.

The problem is that, although this works perfectly well locally, once the application is deployed, [every single symbol is considered invalid and never gets rendered](http://rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com/stocks?symbol=AAPL,GOOG,IBM,GM). For example, AAPL renders a chart locally, but returns "Symbol not found" in the deployed version. I tried removing the exception block and just letting the app crash, but all I see is the 500 error page.

I also tried adding some print-out logging to check when things went haywire. If you're interested, here's the Foreman output:

```
18:15:37 web.1  | testing for length of symbol array...
18:15:37 web.1  | building plots...
18:15:37 web.1  | building data...
18:15:38 web.1  | generating data...
18:15:38 web.1  | building RSI plot...
18:15:38 web.1  | building main plot...
18:15:38 web.1  | building MACD plot...
18:15:38 web.1  | building grid...
18:15:38 web.1  | building snippet...
18:15:38 web.1  | creating signals...
18:15:38 web.1  | AAPL SMA signal says:
18:15:38 web.1  | WAIT
18:15:38 web.1  | AAPL Bollinger breakout signal says:
18:15:38 web.1  | WAIT
18:15:38 web.1  | AAPL RSI signal says:
18:15:38 web.1  | WAIT
18:15:38 web.1  | returning snippet...
18:15:38 web.1  | rendering template...
```

and here's the Heroku logs:

```
2014-01-13T23:38:11.722125+00:00 app[web.1]: testing for length of symbol array...
2014-01-13T23:38:11.722125+00:00 app[web.1]: building plots...
2014-01-13T23:38:11.722125+00:00 app[web.1]: building data...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.226672+00:00 app[web.1]: generating data...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.228213+00:00 app[web.1]: building RSI plot...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.247723+00:00 app[web.1]: building grid...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.248022+00:00 app[web.1]: building snippet...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.236035+00:00 app[web.1]: building main plot...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.243688+00:00 app[web.1]: building MACD plot...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.477185+00:00 app[web.1]: rendering template...
2014-01-13T23:38:12.477185+00:00 app[web.1]: symbol AAPL not found
```

What's *really* weird about these logs is that "symbol AAPL not found" is supposed to print *before* "rendering template", not after, regardless of how many symbols were found or not found. Plus, two of the plots are created after the JS snippet is built. So, things are happening out of order. I have no idea why, unless that's just due to their timestamps...but how would that change things?

I noticed that in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037027/flask-app-failing-on-heroku-but-working-with-foreman), the logs output the traceback if the app crashed. Looking at the stack trace would be immensely helpful so I can see the difference between Foreman's output and the Heroku logs. However, I don't get a traceback in either of the two, so I can't tell what exactly is breaking. (It might also be because of one of the modules I'm using called Bokeh is erroring out, in which case there is nothing I can do on my end since Heroku installs that module itself, and it works on my machine anyway.)

I'm rather mystified as to why it's not working when I deploy it, but works everywhere else. If you want to see it in action, you can [try to pull up Apple's stock page](http://rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com/stocks?symbol=AAPL), but you'll get the "symbol not found" error.

---

Here's all of my code.

routes.py:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
import plots

app = Flask(__name__)


# Define and add a home page.

@app.route('/')  # The base URL for the home page.
def resume():
    return render_template('resume.html')


@app.route('/echo/<message>')
def echo(message):
    # Echos the message passed to it.
    return "%s" % message


@app.route('/stocks')
def lookup():

    s = request.args.get('symbol')

    print "testing for length of symbol array..."

    try:
        len(s)
    except TypeError:
        return render_template('stocks.html',
                               error='Please request a stock symbol.',
                               s_length=0,
                               sd_length=0)

    if len(s) == 0:
        return render_template('stocks.html',
                               error='Please request a stock symbol.',
                               s_length=0,
                               sd_length=0)

    symbols_list = s.split(',')

    snippet_dict = {}

    print "building plots..."
    for i in symbols_list:
        try:
            snippet_dict[i] = plots.build_plot(i.upper())
        except IOError:
            print "symbol %s not found" % i
            continue

    print "rendering template..."

    if len(snippet_dict) == 0:
        return render_template('stocks.html',
                               error='No valid symbols found.',
                               s_length=0,
                               sd_length=0)

    return render_template('stocks.html',
                           snippet_dict=snippet_dict,
                           sd_length=len(snippet_dict))

# Run this thing!
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

plots.py:

```
from bokeh.plotting import *
from bokeh.objects import Range1d

import pandas
import pandas.io.data as web
from pyta import *
import numpy as np

# Creates a set of stock charts in Bokeh.

#Trying to add signals to the indicators.

def sma_signal(sma50, sma200):
    output_array = []
    for i in range(len(sma50)):
        if i == 0:
            output_array.append('BEGIN')
            continue
        if pandas.isnull(sma50[i]):
            output_array.append('WAIT')
        elif sma50[i] > sma200[i]:
            if sma50[i-1] < sma200[i-1]:
                output_array.append('BUY')
            else:
                output_array.append('WAIT')
        elif sma50[i] < sma200[i]:
            if sma50[i-1] > sma200[i-1]:
                output_array.append('SELL')
            else:
                output_array.append('WAIT')
        else:
            output_array.append('WAIT')
    return output_array


def boll_signal(price, upperband, lowerband):
    output_array = []
    for i in range(len(upperband)):
        if price[i] > upperband[i]:
            output_array.append('BUY')
        elif price[i] < lowerband[i]:
            output_array.append('SELL')
        else:
            output_array.append('WAIT')
    return output_array


def rsi_signal(rsi):
    output_array = []
    for i in range(len(rsi)):
        if rsi[i] > 70:
            output_array.append('OVERBOUGHT')
        elif rsi[i] < 30:
            output_array.append('OVERSOLD')
        else:
            output_array.append('WAIT')
    return output_array

# Create a plot for each symbol.


def build_data(symbol):

    data = web.DataReader(symbol, 'google')
    close = data['Close']

    sma50 = sma(close, 50)
    data['SMA50'] = sma50

    sma200 = sma(close, 200)
    data['SMA200'] = sma200

    upperband = bollinger_upper(close, sma50, 50)
    lowerband = bollinger_lower(close, sma50, 50)
    data['Bollinger (upper)'] = upperband
    data['Bollinger (lower)'] = lowerband

    rsi50 = rsi(close)
    data['RSI50'] = rsi50

    macd = macd_line(close)
    signal = macd_signal(macd)
    hist = macd_hist(macd, signal)

    data['MACD Line'] = macd
    data['MACD Signal'] = signal
    data['MACD Histogram'] = hist

    return data



def build_plot(symbol):

    main_plot_title = symbol

    print "building data..."
    data = build_data(symbol)

    # Generate data.

    print "generating data..."
    file_name = '%s.html' % symbol
    output_file(file_name,
                title='How are my stocks doing today?')

    close = data['Close']
    dates = data.index

    # Define plot constants.

    plot_width = 1000

    # Perform TA on stock data.
    # TODO: Make the buy/sell signals actually do something.

    # Define SMA 50/200.
    sma50 = data['SMA50']
    sma200 = data['SMA200']

    # Define Bollinger Bands.
    upperband = data['Bollinger (upper)']
    lowerband = data['Bollinger (lower)']

    # Define RSI.
    rsi50 = data['RSI50']  # TODO: Figure out a way to translate "crosses under/above line" to a sell signal.


    # Define MACD Line, Signal, and Histogram.
    macd = data['MACD Line']
    signal = data['MACD Signal']  # TODO: Actually use these. Figure out subplots!
    hist = data['MACD Histogram']


    # Finished with the data? Then it's time to plot!

    x = data.index
    y = close

    # Plot RSI (remember, it goes on top)

    # Predefine plot for axis buggery.

    print "building RSI plot..."

    rsi_plot = line(x, rsi50,
                    color='#000000',
                    x_axis_type=None)

    # Define RSI axis boundaries.
    x_range = Range1d(start=x[0], end=x[-1])
    xbounds = [x[0], x[-1]]

    curplot().y_range = Range1d(start=0, end=100)
    curplot().x_range = x_range

    yaxis().bounds = [0, 100]
    xaxis().bounds = xbounds

    hold()

    rsi_plot = line(x, rsi50,
                    color='#000000',
                    x_axis_type=None)

    line(x, (np.ones(len(rsi50)) * 30),
         color='#4daf4a')

    line(x, (np.ones(len(rsi50)) * 70),
         color='#e41a1c')

    # Miscellaneous plot attributes.

    rsi_plot.title = main_plot_title
    rsi_plot.height = 200
    rsi_plot.width = plot_width
    rsi_plot.min_border_bottom = 10
    grid().grid_line_alpha = 0.4
    yaxis().axis_label = 'RSI'

    # Remove hold for the main plot.
    hold()


    print "building main plot..."
    # Plot raw stock data (main plot).
    main_plot = line(x, y,
                     color='#1B9E77',
                     legend='Price at Close',
                     x_axis_type=None,
                     title='')

    # Hold for the overlays.
    hold()

    # Plot overlays.

    # SMA 50:
    line(x, sma50,
         color='#D95F02',
         legend='50-day SMA')

    # SMA 200:
    line(x, sma200,
         color='#e7298a',
         legend='200-day SMA')

    # Bollinger shading glyph:
    bandprice = stackify(upperband, lowerband)  # Reverse the upper band data and append it to the lower band data.
    banddates = stackify(dates, dates)  # Do the same for the dates.
    patch(pandas.to_datetime(banddates), bandprice,
          color='#7570B3',
          fill_alpha=0.2)

    # Remove hold, allow for more plots to be added.
    hold()

    # Miscellaneous plot attributes.
    main_plot.height = 600
    main_plot.width = plot_width
    yaxis().axis_label = 'Price (USD)'
    grid().grid_line_alpha = 0.4

    xaxis().bounds = xbounds
    curplot().x_range = x_range

    # Plot MACD.

    print "building MACD plot..."
    macd_plot = line(x, macd,
         color='#D95F02',
         title='',
         x_axis_type='datetime')

    hold()

    line(x, signal,
         color='#1B9E77')

    hold()

    # Attributes.
    macd_plot.height = 200
    macd_plot.width = plot_width
    yaxis().axis_label = 'MACD'

    macd_plot.min_border_top = 0
    macd_plot.min_border_bottom = 100

    # Make a grid and snippet from this.

    print "building grid..."

    plot_grid = gridplot([[rsi_plot], [main_plot], [macd_plot]])

    print "building snippet..."

    snippet = plot_grid.create_html_snippet(embed_base_url='../static/js/temp/',
                                            embed_save_loc='./static/js/temp')

    # Return signal arrays.

    print "creating signals..."

    sma_signals = sma_signal(sma50, sma200)
    boll_signals = boll_signal(close, upperband, lowerband)
    rsi_signals = rsi_signal(rsi50)

    print '%s SMA signal says:' % symbol
    print sma_signals[-1]
    print '%s Bollinger breakout signal says:' % symbol
    print boll_signals[-1]
    print '%s RSI signal says:' % symbol
    print rsi_signals[-1]

    print "returning snippet..."

    return snippet
```

The offending piece of code:

```
print "building plots..."
for i in symbols_list:
    try:
        snippet_dict[i] = plots.build_plot(i.upper())
    except IOError:
        print "symbol %s not found" % i
        continue
```

---

> Do you have anything interesting in the Heroku logs?

This is all I got.

```
2014-01-14T01:24:13.000718+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-01-14T01:24:13.001093+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to starting
2014-01-14T01:24:17.900834+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `gunicorn routes:app`
2014-01-14T01:24:18.796042+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-14 01:24:18 [2] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
2014-01-14T01:24:18.796610+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-14 01:24:18 [2] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:25179 (2)
2014-01-14T01:24:18.796681+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-14 01:24:18 [2] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2014-01-14T01:24:18.802306+00:00 app[web.1]: 2014-01-14 01:24:18 [7] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 7
2014-01-14T01:24:21.078033+00:00 app[web.1]: testing for length of symbol array...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.078033+00:00 app[web.1]: building plots...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.078033+00:00 app[web.1]: building data...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.385022+00:00 app[web.1]: generating data...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.386059+00:00 app[web.1]: building RSI plot...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.390727+00:00 app[web.1]: building main plot...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.398065+00:00 app[web.1]: building MACD plot...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.398388+00:00 app[web.1]: building grid...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.398541+00:00 app[web.1]: building snippet...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.548095+00:00 app[web.1]: symbol AAPL not found
2014-01-14T01:24:21.548270+00:00 app[web.1]: rendering template...
2014-01-14T01:24:21.593435+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stocks?symbol=AAPL host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=5ms service=518ms status=200 bytes=1635
2014-01-14T01:24:21.774327+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/css/main.css host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=4ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=1081
2014-01-14T01:24:21.882153+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/css/continuum.css host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=5ms status=200 bytes=370
2014-01-14T01:24:21.954590+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/js/bokeh.js host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=22ms status=200 bytes=489909
2014-01-14T01:24:21.963913+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/css/normalize.css host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=33ms service=30ms status=200 bytes=7546
2014-01-14T01:24:23.059117+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=12ms status=404 bytes=233
2014-01-14T01:24:21.773260+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/css/bootstrap-bokeh-2.0.4.css host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=19ms status=200 bytes=106102
2014-01-14T01:24:21.861494+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/css/bokeh.css host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=8ms status=200 bytes=2464
2014-01-14T01:24:19.498609+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to up
2014-01-14T01:24:21.903080+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/static/css/unsemantic.css host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=3ms service=10ms status=200 bytes=42798
```

What's interesting is that it actually takes a while for stuff like the last two or three lines to show up, even though they should have happened at the same time.

---

Removing the exception block gets me these logs from Foreman and Heroku, respectively:

```
23:53:45 web.1  | started with pid 8846
23:53:45 web.1  | 2014-01-13 23:53:45 [8846] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 18.0
23:53:45 web.1  | 2014-01-13 23:53:45 [8846] [INFO] Listening at: http://0.0.0.0:5000 (8846)
23:53:45 web.1  | 2014-01-13 23:53:45 [8846] [INFO] Using worker: sync
23:53:45 web.1  | 2014-01-13 23:53:45 [8849] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 8849
23:53:58 web.1  | testing for length of symbol array...
23:53:58 web.1  | building plots...
23:53:58 web.1  | building data...

2014-01-14T04:58:03.316195+00:00 app[web.1]: testing for length of symbol array...
2014-01-14T04:58:03.316195+00:00 app[web.1]: building plots...
2014-01-14T04:58:03.316195+00:00 app[web.1]: building data...
2014-01-14T04:58:05.360351+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stocks?symbol=notasymbol host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=1ms service=2054ms status=500 bytes=291
```

I do not get a 500 error on Foreman, but I do in the logs. It still doesn't seem clear to me *why* I get a 500, though. Obviously, an IOError, but that shouldn't happen for a valid symbol... which it does.

```
2014-01-14T04:57:05.540709+00:00 app[web.1]: testing for length of symbol array...
2014-01-14T04:57:05.540709+00:00 app[web.1]: building plots...
2014-01-14T04:57:05.540709+00:00 app[web.1]: building data...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.170323+00:00 app[web.1]: generating data...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.183668+00:00 app[web.1]: building grid...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.171197+00:00 app[web.1]: building RSI plot...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.176253+00:00 app[web.1]: building main plot...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.180958+00:00 app[web.1]: building MACD plot...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.183783+00:00 app[web.1]: building snippet...
2014-01-14T04:57:06.338506+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path=/stocks?symbol=AAPL host=rpazyaquian.herokuapp.com fwd="69.180.75.108" dyno=web.1 connect=2ms service=809ms status=500 bytes=291
```

Comment: Do you have anything interesting in the Heroku logs?

Comment: @Miguel I don't see anything out of the ordinary, no, but I included a full log from wake-up just now. I'm not sure if there's anything strange about it.

Comment: I don't see any code 500 errors in this log, probably because you are catching and handling. Can you remove the exception handler and try again?

Comment: Without the handler, I get a 500 regardless of what I search for. It doesn't show up in Foreman, but it does in the logs. I included them in the original post.

Comment: Hmm. I'm surprised Heroku isn't showing any error codes of its own in the log. I was hoping that would indicate that (for example) your dyno was running out of memory or was hitting some other limitation. Maybe you should run on debug mode to get a detailed stack trace, or at least log errors from Flask.

Comment: Normally, debug mode does give me a stack trace, but not on Heroku - it only gives me a 500 error. I can try logging, though.

Comment: Ughhh, I figured it out. I had changed the save location for temp files to ./static/js/temp, and that actually didn't exist yet, so the whole thing pooped the bed.

I don't really understand _why_ it won't just make that directory, and running a bash dyno + `mkdir temp` doesn't work, apparently. This should be easy, but it's late. I'll do it tomorrow. Thanks for the help!